# Tons of whitespace on page for no reason

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a website for a restaurant (Not commercially) and need to know why there's so much whitespace to the right side of the page? Take a look

```css
.top-container{
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url("images/charmlogoTrans.png");
    padding: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.menuBar{
    background-color: rgb(168, 123, 81);
    padding: 30px 40px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 3;
}

.content{
    padding:16px;
    background-color:rgba(230,199,177,255);
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-radius:4px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.imgContent{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}

.exampleImg{
       width: 32%;
       height:auto;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 102px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="top-container"></div>
    <div class="menuBar" id="menuBar"> The sticky bar</div>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="imgContent">
            <img class="exampleImg" src="Images/example.png" width="300" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Vestibulum nulla turpis, hendrerit nec sodales vitae, congue at felis. Cras auctor ac quam sed
                fermentum. Quisque libero est, aliquam ac lorem a, semper molestie mi. Cras suscipit eu erat eget
                hendrerit.
            </h3>
        </div>
        <img src="Images/example.png" width="300" height="200">
        <img src="Images/example.png" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
</body>
```

Please excuse me for such messy code, I'm still learning how to do some things. The measurements I'm still working on a bit, but any help is appreciated! If there's anything I've missed, or need to include, please let me know.

Comment: **imgContent** seems to take 50% extra width having `left:50%` and `width:100%`

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to fix the problem. Some basic math haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- That's because `imgContent` is taking `position: absolute`, `left: 50%` so the element will overflow the page because you also set the `width` of `imgContent` to `100%` there's 3 ways to fix this

1. set witdth to less than 100% something like 45% is enough
2. set Left to 0;
3. use flex box instead that's will be better in fact

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to work as well. Would you mind explaining flex boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,

Try this!

It seems that the 50% left was adding the whitespace!

```css
  body {
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 100vw
    }
    
    .top-container {
        background-color: white;
        background-image: url("images/charmlogoTrans.png");
        padding: 170px;
        text-align: center;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .menuBar {
        background-color: rgb(168, 123, 81);
        padding: 30px 40px;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .content {
        padding: 16px;
        background-color: rgba(230, 199, 177, 255);
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-right: 50%;
        margin-top: 2%;
        border-radius: 4px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .imgContent {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 100vw;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .exampleImg {
        width: 32vw;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .sticky+.content {
        padding-top: 102px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="top-container"></div>
    <div class="menuBar" id="menuBar"> The sticky bar</div>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <<div class="imgContent">
            <img class="exampleImg" src="Images/example.png" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Vestibulum nulla turpis, hendrerit nec sodales vitae, congue at felis. Cras auctor ac quam sed fermentum. Quisque libero est, aliquam ac lorem a, semper molestie mi. Cras suscipit eu erat eget hendrerit.
        </h3>
    </div>
    <img src="Images/example.png" width="300" height="200">
    <img src="Images/example.png" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
</body>
```